# Why don't hyperlinks break unless the <a> tags are dived by a newline in the HTML code?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to set a width for a div class which contains a lot of hyperlinks. But it doesn't work. I found out that it works only if every  tag has an own line in the HTML code. Is there any CSS solution to this problem because I am trying to make a tumblr theme and there I won't be able to seperate the  tags in the HTML.

```css
.perma{
    text-align:center;
    width:300px;
    height: auto;
    background: green;
    position:relative;
    display:table;
}
.perma > a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:10px;
    width:20px;
}
.perma > a b{
    display:block;
}
.tags{
    white-space: normal;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height: auto;
}
.tags a{
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="perma">
    <a href=""><b>02</b>02</a>
    <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a><a href="">#link2</a><a href="">#link3</a><a href="">#link4</a><a href="">#link5</a><a href="">#link6</a><a href="">#link7</a><a href="">#link8</a><a href="">#link9</a><a href="">#link10</a><a href="">#link11</a><a href="">#link12</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <br/>
    
    <div class="perma">
    <a href="">
    <b>02</b>02</a>
    <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a>
    <a href="">#link2</a>
    <a href="">#link3</a>
    <a href="">#link4</a>
    <a href="">#link5</a>
    <a href="">#link6</a>
    <a href="">#link7</a>
    <a href="">#link8</a>
    <a href="">#link9</a>
    <a href="">#link10</a>
    <a href="">#link11</a>
    <a href="">#link12</a>
    </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the links `inline-block`

```css
.perma {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

.perma > a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}

.perma > a b {
  display: block;
}

.tags {
  white-space: normal;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: auto;
}

.tags a {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="perma">
  <a href=""><b>02</b>02</a>
  <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a><a href="">#link2</a><a href="">#link3</a><a href="">#link4</a><a href="">#link5</a><a href="">#link6</a><a href="">#link7</a><a href="">#link8</a><a href="">#link9</a><a href="">#link10</a><a href="">#link11</a><a href="">#link12</a>
  </p>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="perma">
  <a href="">
    <b>02</b>02</a>
  <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a>
    <a href="">#link2</a>
    <a href="">#link3</a>
    <a href="">#link4</a>
    <a href="">#link5</a>
    <a href="">#link6</a>
    <a href="">#link7</a>
    <a href="">#link8</a>
    <a href="">#link9</a>
    <a href="">#link10</a>
    <a href="">#link11</a>
    <a href="">#link12</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

You can also use flexbox instead of `display: table;` in this project, and set `flex-wrap: wrap;` on `.tags` so the links will wrap

```css
.perma {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.perma > a {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}

.perma > a b {
  display: block;
}

.tags {
  white-space: normal;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.tags a {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="perma">
  <a href=""><b>02</b>02</a>
  <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a><a href="">#link2</a><a href="">#link3</a><a href="">#link4</a><a href="">#link5</a><a href="">#link6</a><a href="">#link7</a><a href="">#link8</a><a href="">#link9</a><a href="">#link10</a><a href="">#link11</a><a href="">#link12</a>
  </p>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="perma">
  <a href="">
    <b>02</b>02</a>
  <p class="tags">
    <a href="">#link1</a>
    <a href="">#link2</a>
    <a href="">#link3</a>
    <a href="">#link4</a>
    <a href="">#link5</a>
    <a href="">#link6</a>
    <a href="">#link7</a>
    <a href="">#link8</a>
    <a href="">#link9</a>
    <a href="">#link10</a>
    <a href="">#link11</a>
    <a href="">#link12</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hooooly... I spend more than 3 days to find this little mistake in the code... and just in a few minutes: resolved! Thank you a looooot =D

Comment: @DidiKong awesome, no problem.